# Xcode stuck at compiling ios ver 11 while I am using 14 as a target

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

What am I missing here? There is nowhere an instruction to compile for ios 11..

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 11.0, but module 'PhoneNumberKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0:
> /Users/aris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cmtnerpxiupormgiakqsqxlnezts/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/Build
> ProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit.framework/Modules/PhoneNumberKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
> /Users/aris/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/libphonenumber_plugin-0.3.2/ios/Classes/SwiftLibphonenumberPlugin.swift:2:7

Things I have tried:

1. clear build folder from Xcode and run again pod install
2. pod install --repo-update
3. Podfile has first line as target ios: 14
4. Xcode target -> runner -> build settings -> ios build target 14
5. flutter clean; flutter pug get; flutter build ipa
6. flutter upgrade and re-install all pods
7. delete derived folder of Xcode

Comment: The error message you're seeing indicates that you're trying to compile your iOS app with a deployment target of iOS 11.0, but one of the dependencies, which is PhoneNumberKit, has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0. This discrepancy in deployment targets is causing a conflict.

Comment: but my min deployment target is 14. can you tell me where to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this exact error with PhoneNumberKit:

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 11.0, but module 'PhoneNumberKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0:

Update your `ios/Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Do either this:
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
      # or this:
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075795 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072195

Comment: awesome thanks. the fact that we have to manually do these shenanigans is disheartening though :(